# The 2nd derivative test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

[image]

I am having trouble producing a rigorous argument for this. It's clear to my intuition.. just part of the learning process in real analysis is how to make a simple argument rigorous and precise.

Comment: **Hint :** Use Taylor's theorem. More precisely, write $f(x_0+h) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0) h + \frac{f''(x_0)}{2} h^2 + s(h) h^2$ where $s(h) \to 0$ when $h \to 0$.

Comment: $f(x_0 + \Delta x) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0)\Delta x + \frac{1}{2}f''(x_0)\left(\Delta x\right)^2$.  You need the quadratic term since $f'(x_0) = 0$ (note that if $f''(x_0) = 0$ as well, then the test is inconclusive--it's _not_ necessarily an inflection point, e.g. $f(x) = x^4$).

Comment: @Amateur Aren't the error terms of order $h^3$?

Comment: @Jared There are many versions of Taylor's theorem depending on the representation of the remainder term. I believe the one I chose is called Peano's form of the remainder. If $f$ is three times differentiable then I believe you can write $s(h) = \frac{f'''(\xi)}{3!} h$ for some $\xi$ near $x_0$ and this is possibly the error term you are referring to. Does this make sense ?

Comment: @Amateur I guess I've only seen it written $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$

Comment: @Jared Maybe the confusion comes from the fact that in your formula you use the big O notation (of $x^3$) and in mine I use the little-o notation (of $x^2$).

Comment: @Amateur That's probably it.

Comment: @Amateur thanks! that is a fantastic argument. however, I cannot use taylor's theorem as we have not covered that in class (and I doubt i'll be able to prove it!)

Comment: @terribleatmath Actually it's pretty easy to prove.  Assume $f''(0) = a_2$, $f'(0) = a_1$, and $f(0) = a_0$.  You can integrate $f''$ to get $f'$: $f' = \int_0^{t} f'' = a_2t + C$ where $C = a_1$ (plug in $t = 0$).  Then integrate again: $f = \int_0^t f' = \frac{1}{2}a_2t^2 + a_1t + C$...again, $C$ here must be $C = a_0$ (plug in $t = 0$) which gives: $f(t) = \frac{1}{2}a_2t^2 + a_1t + a_0$.  Taylor's theorem just generalizes to having _all_ of the derivatives and not necessarily evaluated at $t = 0$.  I know you still can't use it, but it's actually quite intuitive if you think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $f''(x_0)>0$ means that $f'(x_0)$ is increasing at $x_0$. Since $f'(x_0) = 0$, this means that $f'(x_0-\epsilon) < 0$ and $f'(x_0 + \epsilon) > 0$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. By the first derivative test, $x_0$ must be a local minimum. Apply the converse argument to the case $f''(x_0) < 0$.

Comment: perfect, thanks. that epsilon was just what I needed to make this into a flawless argument.